# Access PortletSession attributes (set by interceptor) from the controller (Spring Portlet MVC)

Tags: java, session, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm new to Spring Portlet MVC, but I've been studying hard on it in the last few days.
The context of my problem is the following

1. I have a Spring Portlet MVC portlet with a single controller.
2. The portlet is **configured to call an HandlerInterceptor** (method 'preHandleRender') anytime a user wants to access to a resource.
3. The interceptor checks if the user is authenticated, if not, it retrieves the user's Liferay credentials to manage authentication on a number of other webservices (not interesting right now).
4. After this, **the interceptor stores the user data inside the PortletSession**.

**Now, how am I supposed to retrieve the user data stored in the PortletSession by the interceptor from inside the controller??**

**sessionInterceptor.preHandleRender**

```
@Override
public boolean preHandleRender(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession(true);
              .
              .
              .
    session.setAttribute("userProfile", userProfileDomain,PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
              .
              .
              .
    return true;
}
```

**ViewController class**

```
@Controller("viewController")
@RequestMapping(value = "view")
public class ViewController {

    //@Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

    @RenderMapping
    public String setModelAndView(RenderRequest request, ModelMap tgtModel) {
        logger.debug("<<  |  >> Starting.");

        PortletConfiguration conf = PortletConfiguration.getInstance();
              .
              .
    }
}
```

I am ready to give further information about my code if requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem and to identify my error.

In the interceptor, as I showed in my question, I set the session attribute "userProfile" **in the PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE.**

```
session.setAttribute("userProfile", userProfileDomain,PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

As for the controller, I understood you have multiple options:

- Pass the request (RenderRequest, in my case) as a parameter, the obtain the session (PortletSession, in my case) from the request and then retrieve the attribute from the session.
- Pass directly the session as a parameter and then retrieve the attribute from it.

However, whether you take the first or the second road, **if you use the following instruction in the controller**

```
session.getAttribute("userProfile");
```

**you wont get anything because the attribute was set in PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE.**

The correct instruction is:

```
session.getAttribute("userProfile",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC wires the PortletSession if you specify it as parameter.

```
 @RenderMapping
 public String setModelAndView(RenderRequest request, PortletSession session, ModelMap tgtModel) {
    logger.debug("<<  |  >> Starting.");

    PortletConfiguration conf = PortletConfiguration.getInstance();
          .
          .
 }
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html#portlet-ann-requestmapping-arguments for the supported types.